# Extract values from jObject in form of string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting this value from kafka topic in the form of string in my Java Script code. How could I extract the JString from this in my Java Script

```
JObject(List(JField(status,JString(done)), JField(session,JString(hello))))
```

Comment: pls provide proper information

Comment: I am getting JObject in the form of String and I want to convert it into JSON so as to extract appropriate values from it.
Anything else which is not clear?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Are you asking us to write you a regex that can extract the `done` and `hello` from a string `"JObject(List(JField(status,JString(done)), JField(session,JString(hello))))"` Or are you asking us how to convert the string `"JObject(List(JField(status,JString(done)), JField(session,JString(hello))))"` into JSON somehow?

Comment: No just convert this string to JSON so that I can use JSON object

Comment: The string is not valid JSON so how could it be parsed?

Comment: Ya I got your point but is there anyway this string could be used to get value of variable status and session

Comment: JOobject, JField, etc are not part of javascript. Use the proper language name to help others know how to help you better. Whichever it is should have a json encoder/decoder

Comment: ok thanks, I will try to use json encoder and decoder